# Fontspec chooses Candara Light instead of Regular

Tags: fontspec

Consider the following LuaLaTex document

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Candara}

\begin{document}
 This is Candara Light, but I want Candara!
\end{document}
```

My understanding is that I ask for the windows font "Candara" quite explicitly. But unfortunately I get the same output as if I had asked for "Candara Light" (which is actually embedded into the pdf) -- which is too light for my taste.

For now, I use the following workaround, which seems a bit verbose to me:

```
\setmainfont{Candara.ttf}[
    BoldFont = Candarab.ttf,
    ItalicFont = Candarai.ttf,
    BoldItalicFont = Candaraz.ttf
]
```

Is this a bug in fontspec or did I miss something important?

Comment: That’s the recommended way to load fonts. You can make it a little less verbose with `\setmainfont{Candara}[Extension=.ttf , BoldFont=*b , ...]`, etc.

Comment: @Davislor My question is more: Why don't I get the font I spelled out but one (somehow arbitrary) variant?

Comment: you could open an issue for luaotfload perhaps one can improve the detecting, but identifying fonts is not an exact art, luaotfload has to guess according to some parameters and as far as I can see both candara.ttf and candaral.ttf says that their weight is normal and they have the same weight parameter. So using the font name is safer.

Comment: Probably has something to do with how the subfamily and full name are set up, but when I test with `fc-match "Candara"` on Windows, I also get Candara Light. You might possibly get a different result with XeTeX and LuaTeX.

Comment: @Davislor Yes, lualatex finds Candara Light, while xelatex finds Candara Regular. `\fontname\font` shows the names as `Candara` and `Candara/OT`, respectively.

Comment: Curioser: Acrobat Reader correctly lists the embedded fonts as Candara-Light and Candara, but in both cases displays Candara Light.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This probably has something to do with how Candara Light lists its Subfamily as “Regular,” its Preferred Family as “Candara,¨ and its Preferred Subfamily as “Light.”  Both luaotfload and XeTeX have to guess which font in a family is the “regular” one based on the name, and an oddball like that can throw one or the other off.  LuaLaTeX and XeLaTeX might not even pick the same font.

The workaround you came up with is the recommended way to load fonts, and you can make it less verbose.  One solution is to save the following as `Candara.fontspec`, in your project folder or local TeX Tree:

```
\defaultfontfeatures[Candara]{
  Ligatures = Common ,
  Extension = .ttf ,
  UprightFont = * ,
  BoldFont = *b ,
  ItalicFont = *i ,
  BoldItalicFont = *z }
```

Refresh your font caches with `fc-cache -f -s -v` and  `luaotfload-tool -f -u -p -v`.  Now, `\setmainfont{Candara}` should work.